# Can I connect the MsSQL Server using Federated Engine in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc, federated-table

Is it possible to connect a SQL Server Database using the Federated Engine in MySQL? I have reviewed the documentation and it appears that the Federated Engine only connects natively to MySQL.
I also found this article:

> You can use the SQL Gateway to configure a MySQL remoting service and set up federated tables for SQL Server data. The service is a daemon process that provides a MySQL interface to the CData ODBC Driver for SQL Server: After you have started the service, you can create a server and tables using the FEDERATED Storage Engine in MySQL. You can then work with SQL Server data just as you would local MySQL tables.

Can anyone suggest a solution or alternative? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you find that article?

Comment: @BillKarwin looks like https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sql-odbc-mysql-federated-tables.rst  it's about https://www.cdata.com/sqlgateway/ which has a free trial download so assume costs $

Comment: Okay that sounds like it's some kind of proxy that serves the MySQL protocol. So one would not be connecting directly to Microsoft SQL Server, but eventually the proxy does provide access to the SQL Server as if it is another MySQL server. Still, this is clearly not a feature of MySQL by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as stated in the manual

> 13.7.3. Limitations of the FEDERATED Storage Engine

> The following items indicate features that the FEDERATED storage engine does and does not support:

> The remote server must be a MySQL server.

http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-limitations.html